Does the UBI 8 image not support OpenSSL versions beyond 1.1.1k?
I have a critical component that relies on OpenSSL version 1.1.1n with custom patches and fixes. Previously, this component was running on a Debian image, but now we are transitioning to UBI8. Despite attempting upgrades and using the latest UBI8.10 version, OpenSSL remains at version 1.1.1k, which is the default supported version in UBI8. Is there a specific reason why I cannot upgrade? Am I overlooking something, or does UBI8 currently not support versions beyond 1.1.1k?
I have tried downloading OpenSSL 1.1.1n directly from the OpenSSL libraries to resolve this issue. However, I also need the openssl-libs package, which is used in UBI8 and cannot be manually downloaded(I guess). The current version provided in UBI8 is only up to version k.
So even If I somehow manage with latest version of openssl or 1.1.1n version. I would be still getting the openssl-libs of k version only.
I need solutions to either work around this issue and achieve compatibility with OpenSSL version 1.1.1n or newer, or solid reasons why achieving this might not be possible.
I've tried using latest version of openssl which was manually downloaded in ubi8 with older version of openssl-libs which was present by default in ubi8.
Mainly Need to figure out a way that we can get both openssl and openssl-libs packages in ubi8 in minimum 1.1.1n version

This UBI 8 image?  That reached EOL over three years ago?  Update it with OpenSSL 1.1.1n?  Which reached EOL almost a year ago?  Lesson here:  do NOT custom patch OpenSSL unless someone signs up for long-term support to maintain those patches.  Ooops. Whoever decided not to do that now gets to revisit that decision.  And you get to tell them.  Lucky you.  Handing this to you to fix was more than a bit unfair.

(cont) And if you continue down this road and use something like OpenSSL 3.0.0, you'll be in the business of building your own container images - FOREVER.  Do you think the people who didn't want to pay for maintaining OpenSSL patches want to pay to be in the OpenSSL patches and container image business?
